# ValueError: No dataset in HDF5 file with pandas.read_hdf from a MatLab h5 file

Tags: python, matlab, pandas, hdf5, h5py

I get a `ValueError: No dataset in HDF5 file.` when using :

```
In [1]: import pandas as pda

In [2]: store = pda.read_hdf('X.h5')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-72e9d80a2c5b> in <module>()
----> 1 store = pda.read_hdf('X.h5')

/usr/local/miniconda3/envs/tensorFlow-GPU/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py in read_hdf(path_or_buf, key, mode, **kwargs)
    356             groups = store.groups()
    357             if len(groups) == 0:
--> 358                 raise ValueError('No dataset in HDF5 file.')
    359             candidate_only_group = groups[0]
    360

ValueError: No dataset in HDF5 file.
```

`h5dump` shows :

```
$ h5dump -n X.h5
HDF5 "X.h5" {
FILE_CONTENTS {
 group      /
 dataset    /DS
 }
}
```

And if I use the `h5py` I can see the data :

```
In [3]: import h5py
/usr/local/miniconda3/envs/tensorFlow-GPU/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h5py/__init__.py:36: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.
  from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters

In [4]: f = h5py.File('X.h5','r')

In [5]: f.keys()
Out[5]: KeysView(<HDF5 file "X.h5" (mode r)>)

In [6]: list( f.keys() )
Out[6]: ['DS']

In [7]: f['DS']
Out[7]: <HDF5 dataset "DS": shape (10, 20), type "<f8">

In [8]: f['DS'][:]
Out[8]:
array([[1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1.,
        0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0.,
        1., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0.,
        1., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.,
        1., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1.,
        0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1.,
        1., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1.,
        1., 1., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.,
        0., 1., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0.,
        1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1.,
        1., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

Comment: Does the `read_hdf`provide any parameters for reading a file that wasn't written by   `pandas/pytables`?  The `h5py` read shows that 'DS' is not embedded in any group; about as plain a `h5` file as possible (the dump confirms that).  I'm a bit surprised since the MATLAB h5 examples that I've seen have the data several layers down, with added type and shape information.

Comment: @hpaulj Hi, [theses Matlab examples](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/h5write.html) using `h5write` clearly shows they are storing their datasets in the root group (`/`)

Comment: I've only looked at `h5` files written by `save` - the newer h5 version of the original `.mat`.  (and more specifically the Octave equivalent).

Comment: `read_hdf` says it `Retrieve pandas object stored in file`.  So it's expecting a file created with `df.to_hdf()`, where `df` is a dataframe or other pandas object.

Comment: @hpaulj OK, thank you :) So if I can sum things up. If the HDF5 file was generated using `pandas` , then I can use `pandas` to read it, else I need to use `h5py`. Is that correct ?

Comment: I don't know if `pandas` has an alternative.  It seems to prefer `pytables` and `HDFStore`.  `h5py` appears to be a better match with `h5write` (though I only glanced at its docs).

Comment: @SebMa I'm new to `HDF5` as well but, yes, I think you need `h5py` to read it, but then you can convert it to a pandas `DataFrame` as `df_f = pd.DataFrame(f['DS'][:])`.